# Is isAdded() same as null != getActivity() in Android Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I wonder if these two methods leads to same results or one is better to use than the other.

```
if(isAdded()){
//do something with activity since fragment is currently added to its activity.
}
```

And

```
if(null != getActivity()){
//do something with activity. Its not null
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`isAdded()` is better to use in pretty much all circumstances for these 2 reasons:

1. `isAdded()` returns true if the Fragment is currently added to its
   activity. `getActivity()` just returns the associated activity. In most cases this will return the same boolean but better to be safe
2. It is less code to write

Source code:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/Fragment.java/

```
/**
 * Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.
 */
final public Activity getActivity() {
    return mActivity;
}

/**
 * Return true if the fragment is currently added to its activity.
 */
final public boolean isAdded() {
    return mActivity != null && mAdded;
}
```

Comment: Implementation of isAdded shows without any doubt that they are not same.